# Machine Vision vs Computer Vision?

Tags: computer-vision

I'm trying to understand the core differences between the two topics.  Is one simply a newer term?  Connotations of automobile vs automation?  Something with a screen vs without?

I've only ever heard the term `computer vision` (tagged).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

These are two different things which share a lot in common.

Simply spoken the CV's task is to perform automatic image processing and then display it to humans.

The MV has to do similar things but you do not get an image as result, you get data.
For example: "There are 6 apples in this image" or "The image shows that the product has a malfunction"

Sources:
http://www.visiononline.org/vision-resources-details.cfm/vision-resources/Computer-Vision-vs-Machine-Vision/content_id/4585